# laravel 5.4 varchar field migration

Tags: php, laravel

When you create a migration and you have a string field like varchar you set it like the code below but I get an error in a migration saying that it's too many bytes

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');            
    $table->string('email')->unique(); 
    $table->timestamps();        
});
```

So if I do this

```
$table->string('email', 255)->unique();
```

Setting it to it's maximum of 255 I still get the same error and I'm sure that 255 is the maximum for a varchar field but if I make the field 250 in the varchar field I get no errors. So what's going on with the migrations in laravel 5.4

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
```

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Character Encoding**

The problem is the Character Encoding on the database. Most likely, you are using a 4 byte encoding. **`utf8mb4`** most likely. If so, 255 (characters) * 4 (byte per char) wont fit the 1000 byte index limit. You mentioned that using 250 removes the problem. That is because it fits the 1000 byte index limit. Try checking your character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions for this: **Upgrade to MySQL 5.7** or use shorter varchars. If you can't upgrade easily, put this to you `AppServiceProvider.php` file - it sets the default string length to a value that'll work.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think unique can be nullable.

how about this `$table->string('slug')->unique();`?

Comment: well I did a migration on users table and I got the same problem for the email field  $table->string('email')->unique();

Comment: Unique can be nullable :)